# How do you conditionally call one php script from another with parameters

Tags: php

As per the title, in php how can you run /execute another php file on the same domain, whilst sending a variable such a POST etc?

So file 1.php has an IF statement that executes 2.php / it's content which also sends a variable to 2.php so 2.php can run properly

I want this to run independently so it can run properly.

So just to execute the script independently, and posting a variable so it can include that variable whilst executing.

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: Can you elaborate at all?

Comment: You're probably looking for `include`, but it's hard to tell with as little as you've said.

Comment: sorry about that - updated.

Comment: include\require\curl\cli\ajax still not clear what you want how about telling us what your *actually* doing rather than beating around the bush

Comment: As a form would post a variable, and execute a page. So that but with no human input - just as a result of an if statement

Comment: which can be done with any of the ideas i suggested (sans ajax) or the answer below. I think the issue is with page2 - i guess it does multiple things depending on how its called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass control to a new script, you could use the header function. using this approach, you'd have to ensure that no other output is being generated by the first script prior to passing control, otherwise header will throw an error.

```
if($test){
    $var = 5;

    header('Location: http://www.example.com/2.php?var=' . $var);
}
```

Then...

```
2.php
<?php
    $varFrom1 = $_GET['var'];
```

Alternatively, I recommend using the include statement which lets you bring in another file and execute the functions contained therein

```
include '2.php';

$variable = "something";

if($test){
    functionIn2($variable);
}
```

You can reference it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php

Comment: I've updated my question. I need it to execute independently whilst also gaining that variable.

Comment: Sorry, I am not following, which file do you want to execute from where?

Comment: So some code in php file 1 runs, provides a variable to a another page file 2 php - it then executes that with the entire page, without including it into page 1

Comment: In the same way you would post a form, but as a result of an IF statment instead. So not human input

Comment: I updated to use the header call to essentially redirect to the next file with a GET variable.

Comment: great that looks like it. On page two how would u define the variable sent

Comment: so you want to user redirected to page 2?

Comment: I assume you need to define the variable in the post, if you want to use it? Do you do it in the same way as you would a form. so  $name = $_POST['var'];   ?

Comment: I updated my answer, in this case it would be a $_GET since it is in the url

Comment: PERFECT - lots of love :D